# Java code quality bulk fix - Strings literals should be placed on the left side when checking for equality

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

We have a huge legacy code base, for which we are trying to fix all Sonar quality issues.

There is issue which says - Strings literals should be placed on the left side when checking for equality. And count of this issue is 12k+.

```
testFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") - non-complaint
"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(testFlag) - complaint
```

I am trying to use **Intelliji IDE Inspection** utility to fix this using "Strutural Search Inspection". How ever, it did not work out.

I have kept search template as

```
$instanceVariable$(equalsIgnoreCase)\(\"$StringLiteral$
```

and replace template as

```
$StringLiteral$(equalsIgnoreCase)\(\"$instanceVariable$
```

But it does not work, is it right way to do/ any better options available in intelliji for this.

I am open to other IDEs like Eclipse. So if there is an option in any open source IDEs, i could try out.

Comment: I think you might want to edit this question and spell "compliant" correctly, because otherwise it means the opposite of what you're trying to say.  :)

Comment: Personally, though, I think the right solution is for your organization to find a better way to spend its time.  The only reason for making sure of the order is because the `String` variable could be `null`--and in my experience, a variable that legitimately could be `null` should be checked and handled explicitly beforehand.  If you really have a case where `"x".equalsIgnoreCase(var)` is correct and `var.equalsIgnoreCase("x")` could throw an exception, I'd say there's a design flaw somewhere, and it would be better for your code quality if you spent the time fixing that.

Comment: @ajb, yes true, we are fixing that - and asked this question on process of fixing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Intellij you should be able to do this via the **Analyze** options.

Probably the easiest option being by **Run Inspection by Name** to limit the inspection to just the one

[image]

Then the inspection you want is  `expression.equals("literal")`, put this in the box that appears and select it, then choose your scope to run the inspection.

You can then fix each occurrence case by case or hit the flip equals button to do them all at once.

[image]

Comment: It is the perfect solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I used `$Instance$.$MethodCall$("$Parameter$")` as my search template and `"$Parameter$".$MethodCall$($Instance$)` as my replacement template.  Under Edit Variables, you can choose `MethodCall` on the left and under Text Constraints, enter `equalsIgnoreCase` in the Text/regexp box.

Verified working in IDEA Community 2017.1.5.

[image: "String Literal On Left Side" tooltip for warning.]

Comment: For Instance and Parameter, what should be the "Text Constraint" while I do edit variables of these two ???

Comment: You don't need one. Only the MethodCall needs to be specified.

Comment: yes, it works. So, specifying nothing in text constraint of these variables refers a blind search ???

Comment: Essentially, yes. If I remember correctly, it breaks on token boundaries by default.